# Can v-tooltip toggle tooltip content visibility by clicking?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-tooltip

I'm using `v-tooltip` plugin that needs to work on mobile devices. Naturally, I had to change trigger since it can't trigger hover on a mobile device.

```
<div
  class="my-tooltip"
  v-tooltip.top="{
    trigger: 'click',
    content: tooltipContent,
  }">
</div>
```

Is it possible to make tooltip content toggle visibility clicking on the same element (div in my case)?

I thought `hideOnTargetClick: true` option would make that possible.

Comment: Both options are working. Can you please elaborate on the issue in detail?

Comment: @NehaSoni Clicking element doesn't toggle tooltip content visibility, it just stays visible. I want content to hide after clicking element again.

Comment: First thing, your div is invisible to the DOM because nothing is written inside it or it has no minimum styling for it to be visible. Second thing, I tried this code and it is toggling the tooltip by clicking on it. I tried this- `<div class="my-tooltip" v-tooltip.top="{trigger: 'click',content: `Hello world`,}">Show Tooltip</div>`

Comment: @NehaSoni yes you're right, in sandbox it's working like I'd want it to, but in my project it doesn't for some reason. I guess I'll have to figure out this one by myself, thanks.